# beamer footnote not showing

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I was wondering what's the appropriate way to add a footnote to a LaTeX `beamer` presentation, because I am trying `\footnote` and it's not showing the footnote. It shows the number but no footnote.

Comment: Please [provide a MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that duplicates your problem. Also include any references to your preamble and the packages you include with regard to your `\footnote` command.

Comment: More specifically, the Beamer manual says "You can use the usual \footnote command." (p. 130)  That is, there is no known incompatibility between a footnote and beamer.  So you will need to show your document as an example (as Werner says) in order for people to diagnose why this functionality is not working for you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is one way of adding a footnote to a beamer presentation. By means of a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{hanging}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hanging
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \hangpara{2em}{1}%
  \makebox[2em][l]{\insertfootnotemark}\footnotesize\insertfootnotetext\par%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \lipsum*[1]\footnote{Here is a footnote}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnote in beamer]

See p 131 of the [`beamer` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

Comment: \footnote[frame] {} would be a little more easy don't you think?

Answer (score 20):

Turning the comment from @user13878 into an answer:

`\footnote[frame]{Here is a footnote}`

This has the advantage of simplicity and compatibility with `\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty`.

Answer (score 9):

Further tuning of the comment of @user13878, the [frame] option of \footnote can be set as default option using

```
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnote[1][]{\oldfootnote[frame,#1]}
```

In fact I'm not so expert to write the above sentences. I could wrote them by  modifying [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100472/beamer-allowframebreaks-default-option) of David Carlisle. Anyway, they worked perfectly with me.

Comment: This is great for LyX users, as it allows using the built-in interface for footnotes with word-processor type formatting rather than having to enter TEX code.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a package called **setspace** then footnotes will not show on beamer. Try doing:

```
\footnote[frame,1]{My footnote}
```