# Beamer allowframebreaks default option

Tags: beamer, macros, optional-arguments

How do I tell beamer that I want `allowframebreaks` allowed by default?

Something like `noitemsep` for itemize: `\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep}`

So that I don't have to do:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    something
\end{frame}
```

but just:

```
\begin{frame}
    something
\end{frame}
```

Comment: A short answer here is going to be 'you can't, at least easily', I'm afraid. Till was really not keen on the idea of auto-breaking frames, and the 'reset' for the appropriate key is buried inside `\beamer@@@@frame`. This can probably be removed using `etoolbox`, and the key then fixed as true using `\setkeys{beamerframe}{allowframebreaks}`. However, this is really against the whole concept of how `beamer` is structured.

Comment: I've read that I shouldn't use `allowframebreaks`, BUT: It makes my life easier and (as the programmer part of me says "keep the code DRY"). Don't have to make frames with identical headings as I can use manual `\framebreak` instead.

Comment: Writing a document isn't coding, and I suspect Till would say that two frames with the same title suggests that they are actually a (sub)section and you're abusing the title of the frame :-) More importantly, presentations are visual things, and therefore automatic breaking is very unlikely to make good decisions.

Comment: Just in case someone is looking at this question looking for a way to set default frame options (in general): [my answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129544/169) might provide some help.

Comment: @JosephWright What if you want to use the section title as the frame title?

Comment: @cfr Use a style that puts the section name in the frame header, I guess

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since everyone is telling you not to do it, here;s one way of doing it:-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\oldframe\frame
\renewcommand\frame[1][allowframebreaks]{\oldframe[#1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

That leaves breaking as the default option but if you specify any other option the default 
is not used so you need to include `allowframebreaks` whenever you have an option.

If you definitely always want it (rather than just having it as default if no option used) you can use instead of the above

```
 \renewcommand\frame[1][]{\oldframe[allowframebreaks,#1]}
```

so that `allowframebreaks` is always prepended to the option list.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina sure, but you can either include allowframebreaks whenever you have an option or if you definitely always want it (rather than just having it as default if no option used) you can use `\renewcommand\frame[1][]{\oldframe[allowframebreaks,#1]}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina OK will do

Comment: Has this stopped working (texlive 2013), or is it just me? I redefine exactly as you say, and get "`Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup`" as soon as it reaches the first frame. If it's just me I'll investigate further...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it doesn't work if you load the parameter `fragile` `\begin{frame}[fragile]` can you invistigate that please ?

Comment: @SAM probably you're better to ask a new question ref this, someone who knows the beamer code will probably pick it up:-)

Comment: For some reason this breaks when doing `\frame{\titlepage}`.