# Macro- allowframebreaks as default returns error when loaded with fragile

Tags: beamer, macros

This is a follow-up question to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100496/92620).

I noticed that the macro proposed returns error if the frame is loaded with the parameter `fragile \begin{frame}[fragile]`. Note that when issuing manually

`\begin{frame}[fragile,allowframebreaks]`

it doesn't  returns any error (and it's not a question of parameter order).  Why ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\oldframe\frame
\renewcommand\frame[1][]{\oldframe[allowframebreaks,#1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{enumerate}
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\item    something \item    something \item    something
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Most likely `frame` does not see the correct `\endframe` code anymore

Comment: That's one of the many reasons you should neither have `allowframebreaks` nor `fragile` as default options.

Comment: Redefining `\frame` is a very bad idea. It's a rather complicated command and your naive redefinitionis too naive.

Comment: @samcarter Yes. Though the OP is not setting `fragile` as default.

Comment: @egreg It is David's redefinition, isn't it?

Comment: @egreg yes it's [David's redefinition](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100496/92620) not mine, the macro should works for all combinations as long as the argumentsare valid vis-a-vis the environment `frame`

Comment: @samcarter i agree that setting the option `allowframebreaks` is a bad idea, but the question is why the macro programatically doesn't work in this case?

Comment: See p61 of the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Do not try this at home! Not intended for individual, collective, aggregative, national, international, supranational, global, solar, intersystem, intergalactic or universal use for commercial, non-commercial, public, private, semi-private or third sector purposes.**

## *Caveat emptor*

---

The manual has this to say about `fragile` and `environment` (pp 60-1):

> - `fragile` ... tells beamer that the frame contents is “fragile.”
>     This means that the frame contains text that is not “interpreted as
>     usual.” For example, this applies to verbatim text, which is,
>     obviously, interpreted somewhat differently from normal text.
>
>   If a frame contains fragile text, different internal mechanisms are
>     used to typeset the frame to ensure that inside the frame the
>     character codes can be reset. The price of switching to another
>     internal mechanism is that either you cannot use overlays or an
>     external file needs to be written and read back (which is not always
>     desirable).
>
>   In detail, the following happens when this option is given for normal
>     (pdf)LaTeX: The contents of the frame is scanned and then written to a
>     special file named `⟨jobname⟩.vrb` or, if a label has been assigned to
>     the frame, `⟨jobname⟩.⟨current frame number⟩.vrb`. Then, the frame is
>     started anew and the content of this file is read back. Since, upon
>     reading of a file, the character codes can be modified, this allows
>     you to use both verbatim text and overlays.
>
>   To determine the end of the frame, the following rule is used: The
>     first occurence [*sic.*] of a single line containing exactly
>     `\end{⟨frame environment name⟩}` ends the frame. The `⟨environment
>     name⟩` is normally `frame`, but it can be changed using the
>     `environment` option. This special rule is needed since the frame
>     contents is, after all, not interpreted when it is gathered.
>
>   ...
> - `environment=⟨frame environment name⟩`. This option is useful only
>     in conjunction with the `fragile` option .... The `<frame environment name>` is used to determine the end of the scanning when gathering the
>     frame contents. Normally, the frame ends when a line reading
>     `\end{frame}` is reached. However, if you use `\begin{frame}` inside
>     another environment, you need to use this option ...
>
>   ... [because
>     otherwise] TeX would “miss” the end ... since it does not interpret
>     text while gathering the frame contents.

Modifying the example on 61, you could, therefore, use this to work around the various constraints.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% modified from example on p 61
\newenvironment{slide}[1][]
{%
  \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,#1]%
  }{%
  \end{frame}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}[fragile,environment=slide]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item    something \item    something \item    something
    \item    something \item    something \item    something
    \item    something \item    something \item    something
    \item    something \item    something \item    something
    \item    something \item    something \item    something
    \item    something \item    something \item    something
    \item    something \item    something \item    something
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{verbatim}
    \macro \macro \macro
  \end{verbatim}
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

[image: autobreaks with fragile content]

Comment: thank you for your time and explanation cfr i am sure it wasn't not an easy thing to understand.

Comment: This way of handling fragile content crops up reasonably often. It is not specific to Beamer.

Comment: You forgot warnings about usage in parallel universe and extra-dimensions :)

Comment: How can I have the title in this slide env?