# Global frame breaking in beamer

Tags: beamer

I don't want to use the option `allowframebreaks` in every single frame like

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    Text
\end{frame}
```

Is there a way to set it globally?

Comment: Your question is already answered here: [Beamer allowframebreaks default option](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100472/110998).

Comment: @gernot Thank you for your suggestion but I have already see that question and it doesn't mention what I asked. All it describes is a custom implementation and I already have implemented one.

Comment: 'No' in the sense that the `beamer` internals quite deliberately reset the value for each frame. Hence the need to 'roll you own' if you are definite.

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you for the definitive answer! :P

Comment: @Adam No. As I said, your question is answered there. If you read the comments immediately below the question, they tell you exactly what Joseph says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with defining new command ...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand\breakframe{\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]}

\begin{document}
\breakframe
    Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure, if you consider all possible consequences of this wish. With it some features of Beamer is lost (like uncover). My solution is rather rude, but works

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I already do it with a custom command. I just thought that a global way would exist. If there is not I will accept your answer as a reference for future readers.