# Always* insert a fixed slide after the title slide

Tags: beamer, themes

I'm implementing my institution's PP templates -- like so many others. At our organisation we're often presenting classified stuff and we're supposed to include a slide with information about classification and remind people to take their electronics out of the room.

Ideally, the user shouldn't have to remember to include this slide by herself: If beamer is told that that the presentation contains classified information, then it should automatically insert this slide after the title page. For now, let's just assume there exists a boolean `classified`.

As a workaround, I could do it as a transition on the title page template. However, that would look very strange when printing.

It feels like this question is related to [Theme with a different footline for the titlepage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317938/theme-with-a-different-footline-for-the-titlepage?noredirect=1&lq=1) (in principle, insert some stuff before and after should be equivalent?), but I haven't been able to proceed.

There is no MWE, as I don't even know where to begin. As such, I'm happy to just get pointers in the right direction, and I'll make sure to post a working result at the end.

Comment: Maybe some like `\deb\classified{\begin{frame}\frametitle{Classified} Get the damn phones out of this room \end{frame}}` somewhere in the in the preamble/ external preamble/custom package/custom class,  and then simply use `\classified` classified information or do nothing for not classified material ?

Comment: @Fran, just to check if I understand you correctly: The user should add \classified themselves to get that slide? It is of course a safe fall-back option, but I wanted to explore the possibility of the user not having to do anything. :-)

Comment: What do you mean with "anything"? The template must guess what the user wants?   The user must write in someway that presentation is classified, right? None more simple that uncomment `%\classified`  when needed. If you are thinking really in some more complex that press `Del`  (a mandatory switch, or include information in  `\maketitle`, AI to determine when is classified (haha), etc.)  you will have to be more specific about your needs.

Comment: @Fran I realise I've been somewhat vague. I'm setting the classification when importing the theme, `\usetheme[classification=nr]{institutiontheme}`. Hence, having an extra `\classified` is -- information theoretically -- redundant information. (It's basically a question of over-the-top style. I principle, I want the user to be able to start with a completely blank document, and use only what he knows from vanilla Beamer. I might have to abandon that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally opted to use a variation of @Fran's suggestion in the comments above. A justification to future people like me follows below. In the style of @Marijn's code:

`iooci.sty`

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\institute{Institute of Often Classified Information}   % default institute and logo
\logo{\fbox{\Huge IoOCI}}

\setbeamertemplate{classificationframe}{%
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Classified}
    This presentation is classified
  \end{frame}
}
```

Document

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{iooci}
\author{John Smith}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\usebeamertemplate{classificationframe}

\begin{frame}{First real slide}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Why not anything more fancy? I figured I had to tell the user how to do stuff nonetheless, so I opted for the most straight-forward solution.

Along the way, I explored using `[allowframebreaks]` (see [Beamer allowframebreaks default option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100472/beamer-allowframebreaks-default-option)), but if I redefined the `frame` to allow me to put the classification info on the title page template, it could potentially break how the user expected new frames to work, including `\frame{\titlepage}` and frames with `[fragile]`.

Fran and Marijn, thanks for taking the time to answer a vague question. It helped me explore my possibilities.

Any better solutions than the one I ended up with are obviously still welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the title page and a conditional 'Classified' frame in a style file. The frames can be inserted using the `AfterEndPreamble` hook from the `etoolbox` package, which is executed at the end of the `\begin{document}` command.

MWE, `iooci.sty`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newif\ifclassified
\classifiedtrue   % set boolean to true by default
\institute{Institute of Often Classified Information}   % default institute and logo
\logo{\fbox{\Huge IoOCI}}
\AfterEndPreamble{
{%
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % switch off navigation symbols 
\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}            % and logo for first two slides
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\ifclassified   % show slide only if boolean is true
\begin{frame}{Classified}
This presentation is classified
\end{frame}
\fi % end if
}   % end scope of switching off navigation and logo
}
```

Document with extra slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{iooci}
\author{John Smith}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{First real slide}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And without:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{iooci}
\author{John Smith}
\date{\today}
\classifiedfalse
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{First real slide}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result (with extra slide):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's almost what I hoped for, with the only drawback being the assumption that there will be only one title slide, and that it always appears first. I guess it can be remedied turning the code in the hook handler into a new command, and then documenting that for the users.

I'll leave the question open for a little longer before accepting, just in case someone knows about some pure magic.