# how can I move the footnote in the far left or adjust it

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I am preparing a presentation, I know some people don't like figure to be used for presentation etc. however, it is what I know and it works for me so I keep it simple as I can manage it :-)

I want to move the footnote in the bottom of the page to the far left, is it possible to do that ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption} 

\begin{document}
\section{My photo}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{my photos}
\footnotesize\textbf Is this the same as previous figure?
\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{This is an amazing photo\footnote{\url{https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/figure-1/}}}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{photo1.jpg}
\end{figure}
\footnotesize  This figure comes from a very good photographer \footnote{\tiny Definition of figure (Entry 1 of 2)}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it really makes no sense to use `figure` for a presentation, the only reason ever to use figure is to allow the text to be moved to help with automatic page breaking, that isn't something you want in a presentation. It's also impossible to have page level footnotes from a figure as it is a float box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with use suggestion in answers to question [beamer-footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27626/beamer-footnote-not-showing):

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}

\usepackage{hanging}
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \hangpara{0.8em}{1}%
   \makebox[0.8em][l]{\scriptsize\insertfootnotemark}\scriptsize\insertfootnotetext\par%
}

\begin{document}
\section{My photo}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{my photos}
\footnotesize

Is this the same as previous figure?
\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{This is an amazing photo\footnote{%
    \href{https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/figure-1/}
         {\scriptsize https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/figure-1/}}}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{photo1.jpg}
\end{figure}
This figure comes from a very good photographer\footnote{Definition of figure (Entry 1 of 2) \vspace{1.5ex}}  % <---
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:** it seams that default position of footnotes are bottom of frames (if a `\footnote` is outside `minipage` or some box). for lifting them for some vertical space above frame bottom, you have two possibilities:

- increase distances between footnotes with

  ```
  \addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{}{\vspace{1.5ex}}
  ```
- in the last `footnote` in the frame add on its end for example `\vspace{1.5ex}` as is done in above *mwe*
- i do not know, if exist solution which will automatically add some vertical space below last footnote in the frame, i.e, move footnotes above frame footer.

Comment: can you bring the footnote a bit higher ?

Comment: @Learner, see edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-figure version.  You should put `\captionof` inside a group or environment (it sets `\@captype` locally), so I used the `center` environment.  My first choice would normally be minipage, but it does footnotes internally.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption} 

\begin{document}
\section{My photo}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{my photos}
\footnotesize\textbf Is this the same as previous figure?
\begin{center}
\captionof{figure}{This is an amazing photo\footnote{\url{https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/figure-1/}}}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}\par
\end{center}
\footnotesize  This figure comes from a very good photographer \footnote{\tiny Definition of figure (Entry 1 of 2)}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```